# Creating a Dynamic ojTable Using OJET

Tags: oracle-jet

I have a JSON data with n number of rows and n number of columns. I need to create a table out of it to display the results with pagination.Is there a possibility to create a  ojtable with dynamic number of rows and columns from JSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rows will be handled for you by the component based on the number of rows of data in the JSON file.  If you want to limit the number of rows shown at the start, then set the The columns option for the ojTable can be passed an object which would dynamically set the columns that should be displayed.

Something like this:

```
<table data-bind="ojComponent: {component: 'ojTable', 
        data: pagingDatasource,
        columns: dynamicCols}">
</table>

self.getCols = function () {
  var url = getUrl();
  $.getJSON(url).then(function (data) {
    var tempCols = [];
    for (var property in data.items[0]) {
      if (data.items[0].hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        tempCols.push({headerText: property, field: property});
      }
    }
    self.dynamicCols(tempCols);
    self.pagingDatasource(new oj.PagingTableDataSource(new oj.ArrayTableDataSource(data.items, {idAttribute: 'empno'})));
}
```

Here is a jsFiddle that shows how to do it.  You can (un)comment between the two URL's to see the different generated tables based on the JSON being returned by the REST endpoints. https://jsfiddle.net/peppertech/mdp0xjh3/

Comment: Nice info. In my scenario all the columns are dynamic. So for this case how can use the `idAttribute` in `ArrayTableDataSource`. I tried by setting `idAttribute: null` as I don't want any idAttribute but when user add or delete the columns dynamically then ended up with the error `Uncaught Error: Specified idAttribute <column_name> not in row data. Please ensure all specified idAttribute fields are in the row data or do not specify idAttribute and all fields will be used as id.`

Comment: @Karthi1234 if you leave idAttribute out completely, the datasource will use the index as the primary key.  This can be dangerous for you down the road if you do not properly define your delete statements.  Databases like to have unique id's for this exact reason.  That is what idAttributes is really looking for. You could possibly set the value of idAttribute to a variable that is set at runtime as well.  I haven't tried that myself.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I have added the runtime serial number for the number of data and used that one as idAttribute and all good now. In my case no need to update database.